# Is the following `readonly` use POSIX-ly correct?

Tags: variable, posix, readonly, shell-builtin

I defined the following as read-only:

```bash
readonly root_command='sudo -s'
```

later used in my script as in:

```bash
exec $root_command
```

My question is, maybe I am *slow* or something, but I do not fully understand the [POSIX man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readonly.1p.html), as for example if I can single quote or have to double quote and similarly what the `-p` option is for?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see how quoting is related. I mean, `readonly` merely means that the variable cannot be modified or unset. Everything else is just the same as the case in which `readonly` is not used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Per POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#readonly), `readonly` has two forms:

1. `readonly var`, which marks the shell variable `var` as read-only, and can optionally assign a value to `var` simultaneously (`readonly var=value`).
2. `readonly -p`, which outputs the names and values of all read-only variables.

They are never combined; you either use `-p` to see all current read-only variables, or you use `readonly` to mark a variable as read-only (without `-p`).

When you mark a variable as read-only, you can also give it a value (which will be its value for good, since it can’t be changed afterwards). This is the same as any variable assignment, and since it takes the form `var=value`, where `value` is a word, you need to quote as appropriate, with the same rules as usual (single quotes to prevent variable expansion, double quotes to allow it, etc.).

Note that `exec $root_command` depends on the current value of `$IFS`, and it’s better to use functions rather than variables to store commands.

Comment: Strictly speaking POSIX does not specify what `readonly -p var` does, so you must not use it in compliant/portable sh scripts. In practice, you'll find some shells that output the definition of the variable, some only if that variable is readonly, some where the `-p` option is ignored. `readonly -p var=value` wouldn't make much sense but is also handled differently be different `sh` implementations in practice.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas right, I didn’t go into detail beyond plain `readonly -p` (with no further argument) because it’s unspecified.